# How to Change IBAction Event Type Once Created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

When I control+drag to my .m from a text field to create an IBAction it asks for what type of events should this IBAction be called. I mistakenly set the wrong event type (Editing Did End) and want to change it to Editing Changed.

This is minor, I know, because I can just create the new IBAction with the correct event and copy the innards, but I'd like to know if changing the event of an already created IBAction is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on textview.
Remove IBAction for Editing Did End.
Set to Editing Changed.